# Transposing an equation: x = F/k + sqrt(F/c) to get F as the subject

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For a question, I have been given this equation:

x = F/k + sqrt(F/c)

and told to get an equation that, given values of x,k and c; can be solved for F.
I assumed that this meant that I had to transpose this equation to make F the subject of the equation. 
However, I found this difficult to do, as all my attempts ended up with me having F terms trapped on both sides, or being stuck with k's and c's around the F, and just generally not being able to get the right answer.

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $$c\cdot\left(\sqrt{\frac{F}{c}}\right)^2 + k\cdot\sqrt{\frac{F}{c}} - xk = 0.$$